# Convert number value from php to varbinary in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, varbinary

In MYSQL database, I have a `varbinary(255)` field.

In my PHP script, I am trying to pass the input of string (either in decimal or hex) to MYSQL to save the value in varbinary(255). I tried passing the value in decimal, hexadecimal, and binary, but none of them gave me the correct value.

```
$val = "0x54321";                   // Used hardcoded hex value here, but it can be also decimal in my code
$v_dec = intval($val,0);            // That's why I have intval() here
$v_hex = dechex(intval($val,0));
$v_bin = decbin(intval($val,0));
$v_bin_2 = (binary)intval($val,0);
```

I tried inserting these values using regular `INSERT` query, but each of them gave weird numbers.

```
Variable  Converted Value (in php)    varbinary Value (in MYSQL)      
v_dec:    344865                 ->   333434383635
v_hex:    54321                  ->   3534333231
v_bin:    1010100001100100001    ->   31303130313030303031313030313030303031
v_bin2:   344865                 ->   333434383635
```

What data type should the value be in? I want to do the conversion in php instead of using `CAST()` in the MYSQL query. Thanks!

EDIT:
What I want to do is to correctly display the saved varbinary value in hex.

EDIT: 
Found the problem. The problem was how I was retrieving the value. Instead of `HEX(value)`, I retrieved it as `BIN(value)` in mysql level and then converted it into hex with `dechex(bindec($value))` in php.

Comment: If you use prepared statements the conversion should be taken care of if you specify the correct binding. How are you executing your query?

Comment: I use pdo functions to prepare and execute the queries.

Comment: Every value but `$v_dec` is a string, which will be treated very differently than numbers. And is the varbinary you show the value returned by a query, or just as displayed in, like, Adminer?

Comment: That is the value showing up in mysql database, phpmyadmin. Also, that is the value I get when I query `SELECT HEX(data)`.

Comment: If you use PDO you should be able to bind arbitrary binary values to placeholders. There nothing special you have to do here.

Comment: I am using the PDO prepare and execute... But as you can see, the same hex value is being stored as different varbinary values...